# Bootstrap 3 Image will not fill Carousel, stuck at left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've been trying to get this carousel to work for a couple hours now, but I don't seem to be receiving the desired results and the docs at getbootstrap.com are not very specific as to any nuance involved with this (usually you can just copy paste their code and it works).

Basically, I have the default code from the [first example here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples) with my modifications:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="center-block" src="assets/img/rate-shop-black.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Rate Shopping Tool</h3>
                        <p>Always get the best rates possible when using our best-in-class rate shopping tool.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="center-block" src="assets/img/rate-shop-black.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Rate Shopping Tool</h3>
                        <p>Always get the best rates possible when using our best-in-class rate shopping tool.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="center-block" src="assets/img/rate-shop-black.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Rate Shopping Tool</h3>
                        <p>Always get the best rates possible when using our best-in-class rate shopping tool.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

One of the resources I found [Carousel image doesn't fill the width in bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638276/carousel-image-doesnt-fill-the-width-in-bootstrap-3) mentions setting the width="100%" on the Img tag, but that causes the image to blow up to astronomical proportions.

Another resource I found mentioned making the image larger, so I went into `variables.less` and found the width of `@screen-lg` to be set to `1200px` so I went back to Gimp and increased the base canvas size to `1200px`. This looks better, but there is still at least a full inch on either side of the image in the carousel that are showing pure white before the gradient begins on the `.carousel-control` elements.

It's also worth noting that the images 'stick' to the left of the carousel unless I apply the `.center-block` class to them, which bring me closer to my desired effect and isn't an issue.

I'm wondering if I should increase the image size again, and if so by how much? How big do images need to be for full-page (no `.container`) carousels? What about those wrapped in a `.container`?

Or am I missing some part of the markup that is causing this to happen?

Below is an image of what I currently see being produced.

[image: Shows current result from the above HTML]

Comment: Basically the image is behaving as it should. 
Setting the width of the img tag to %100 will make the image stretch to 100% of it's parent. Which I assume is the .carousel-inner class.
So two options. Set the parent width of .carousel-inner to the desired px width and then set the img tag to 100%, or continue to tweak the size of the img tag until you are happy.

Comment: @AlexGrant I appreciate that, but when I set the image width to 100% it completely fills the screen (and I'm on a pretty big monitor). Do you know by chance what Image sizes I should be using for this?

Comment: Well depends on your taste. 

Try setting the parent to max-width:1400px; width: 100%; 

then set the img tag to width: 100%;

Comment: Alex is right...you either need to make the parent have a max-width so that the image doesn't stretch out too much, or you need to let the image stretch.  If the image stretches, you can use a bigger version of the image to make it look better, but then you are requiring users to download a bigger file...everything is a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsFiddle for you.

Setting the parent slider width to 100% with a max-width of 1400px; will centre the slider and not go too large when on a large monitor. You can adjust the max-width property to your liking.

http://jsfiddle.net/4sBED/1/

```
#carousel-example-generic {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```